# how to choose the best plot method

Tags: python, tkinter

if I have 'Sales.xls' file that has five columns as follows:
Milk, Olives, Sugar, Rice, and Snacks.

with rows representing the monthly sale of the good for months 1 to 12.

Now, if I used a GUI that asks the user to choose from these goods and plot its sales per month:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZR1q.jpg

what is the best way to draw the chosen goods?
I mean, the user can pick 120(5!) selection.

Comment: "Best way" in what sense? Type of plot or what plotting module to use?

Comment: what plotting module to use.
because I think it is not consistent to do 120 if statements each with a separate plot.

Comment: Many folks here seem to be using `matplolib`. Here's [link](http://queirozf.com/entries/matplotlib-pylab-pyplot-etc-what-s-the-different-between-these) to an article that compares several of them. Note that questions as for software recommendations are off-topic for this website.